# Plotting a 20 MHz RF wave in Excel

Tags: frequency, radio, plot, wavelength

How can I plot "F1(t) = 20MHz" in Excel?

I will eventually put it into mathcad. The amplitude would be a variable as well but lets pick 4.5 for now. Just  get the 20 MHz wave to look how it should.

20,000,000 cycles in t=1 sec. I think I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: Do you want to plot \$f(t) = 20\ \rm MHz\$, or do you want to plot \$x(t)=A\sin(2\pi(20\ {\rm MHz})t)\$?

Answer (score 1):

Plotting \$f(t)=20\ {\rm MHz}\$:

[image]

Plotting \$x(t) = \sin\left(2\pi(20\ {\rm MHz})t\right)\$:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the codes that you used? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What fidelity do you want?  Think of the rows of excel as individual ADC samples, the number of rows that you take to construct the wave is going to define how many waves you get before excel runs out of rows, and will determine the fidelity (granularity if you will) of the waveforms.  I like Nyquist as much as the next guy, well maybe a lot less.  I would imagine that you will want to have at least 5 rows to the wave and you probably want to have a non-integer number so that over the course of many waves you carve out every angle in the wave.

[image]

It's technically open office, not excel, but I'm using the formula =K2+$H$5 for the time increments (previous row + "time per row"), and =SIN(K3*$H$2*2*PI()) for the "wave" column.  This is "sin("time column" * "20MHz" * (2*pi()))", because remember, everybody thinks in radians